# Remove macOS from current dual boot system

Tags: macos, windows, dual-boot

Is it possible to remove macOS from my system which currently has macOS Sierra and Windows 10? If so could someone explain or direct me to a resource/guide?

I think the last time I tried to remove macOS I couldn't boot Windows anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a significant hardware or software change, then Windows may fail to boot. In these cases, you need to rebuild the `bcd` file. The software to do this is included in the Windows installation files. So you need to boot to a Windows installer to run these commands. The procedure depends on how your Mac is configured.

Some items to consider are given below.

- Does Windows boot using a legacy BIOS or the newer EFI.
- Can you boot Windows from a optical drive, flash drive or other method.

It would be best to have a way to boot to a windows installer, before removing macOS. Then again, you may not need the Windows installer at all.